# Open WebMatrix SQL Server database in Microsoft SQL Server Management studio

Tags: sql, webmatrix

I have a question. I did migrate my SQL CE database to SQL Server database and now i would like to open this SQL Server database in Microsoft SQL Server Management studio. Do you knoq how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I need more information to help you, are you having trouble determining the server or the login or what? You need to login as a user with rights on that database. Do you know the server name that it was migrated to?

If you are looking for an easy to use tool to convert between mssqlce and sqlserver try this one: http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/69910